# How to navigate to a screen which has BottomNavigationBar and change a tab of BottomNavigationBar at the same time?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to navigate screen and change tab in bottomNavigationBar at the same time.

```
....

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  ...

  Widget selectedAppBar(int index) {
    ...
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: selectedAppBar(_selectedIndex),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: _screenOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigation(
          onChangeScreen: _onChangeScreen,
          selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
        ),
      );
  }

  ...
}
```

other page, there is a bottom and when I click it so will be navigation to main screen and also change tab of BottomNavigationBar

```
....

class _ItemState extends State<ItemPage> {

  ItemScreenArguments _screenArguments;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _screenArguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    final item = _screenArguments.item;

    return BlocBuilder<CartBloc, CartState>(
      builder: (BuildContext context, CartState state) {
        ...

        final cart = (state as LoadCartState);
        return Scaffold(
          extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
          appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            title: Text(item.name),
              actions: [
                Basket(
                  count: cart.count,
                  onTap: () {
                   // It should navigate main route and fourth section in bottomNavigationBar
                   Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('/main'))
                  },
                )
              ]
            ),
            body: ItemScreen(),
            ...
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

I try that do it is using Bloc or it's bad idea to use Bloc?

May be, using Router MaterialPageRoute better than Bloc or using them together? How to you do it? Can you help to choose better option?

Comment: I am sorry, I wrote incorrectly, Ich meinte, I have 2 pages and one of page has bottom navigation It is Main and other page hasn't bottom navigation. Then I should navigate from itemPage to MainPage and into MainPage changes tab of BottomNavigation at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send the **tab number** you want to select by default

```
Navigate.of(context).pushNamed("/main",arguments:{'tab':3})
```

You can retrieve this tab number using **ModalRoute** and set **_selectedIndex** accordingly

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final route= ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String,int>;
   var _selectedIndex = route['tab']

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: selectedAppBar(_selectedIndex),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: _screenOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigation(
          onChangeScreen: _onChangeScreen,
          selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
        ),
      );
  }
```

Comment: I know it. I wrote incorrectly. I have to navigate from item to main and in main changes tab of bottomNavigatorBar

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope it helps to solve your problem. Feel free to ask if your problem is not solved.

Comment: Yes, Thank you, I did .